# What is the syntax to print the last value of the column?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I need to print the last value of the column. Is there is any code for this in rails?

```
SELECT LAST(column_name) FROM table_name;
```

Comment: Do u have any unique columns? like `id`?

Comment: S latest value @usmanali

Comment: Yes. i have @Crazy2crack

Comment: I am guessing you want something like `SELECT column_name FROM table_name ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1`. Right?

Comment: Yeah, crct @usmanali

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
StockAvailability.order('created_at DESC').first.qty
```

Comment: if you find this answer helpful you can mark it as accepted or upvote it. Please follow these guidelines http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

```
Model.last.column_name
```

This will work.

If you just want to show recent quantity no need to loop through all `stock_availabilities` Just get last one and print it's `qty`, Like below:

```
d.stock_availabilities.last.qty
```

Will show last quantity.